# How to put map bindy for length not fixed from certain position?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, apache-camel, bindy

I have a long string which have two fields with certain length and another field length is not known. So how to map bindy fixed length in this case?
I have a string like this:

```
String info ="samulDavidThis is my story";
```

and  my object is like this :

```
@DataField(pos=1, length=4)
private String name;
@DataField(pos=5, length=4)
private String lname;
private String story;
```

After position 9 the length of story is not fixed so can someone help me how to map for the story?

Comment: Is lname the last field? Then I think you may not need to set a length and bindy will use until end of line

Comment: no after lname there is a another field name which is story.So need to put all the remaining value in story field